# How to target specific div from another page using jquery?

Tags: jquery

So this is a common question I guess and I got the same answers from other thread(s) but when I tried to apply the answer it's not working in my case. So I want to target a specific div from another page using jquery.
Here is my code:

```
   $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var target = this.hash;
    var t = $(this.hash).offset().top;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: t,
    }, 1000, function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
```

So for example I have a menu like:

```
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                <li class="active dropdown">
                    <a class="border menu_link_3" href="jewellery">Jewellery </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#kalis-pearls">Kalis Pearls</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#mariana">Mariana</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="border menu_link_4" href="manufacturing">Manufacturing</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#handmade-jewellery">Handmade</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#computer-graphic-jewellery-design">Computer Graphic</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#gem-sourcing">Gem Sourcing</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

So the `Jewellery` is my active menu and when I try to go to `Manufacturing` menu sub pages it gives me an error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null
```

What I'm missing here?

Comment: Are you sure the elements with those ID's exist? If not then `offset()` would be null. Provide enough html to replicate the problem. A demo would help

Comment: Can you replicate the issue on fiddle?

Comment: Are you this is what you intended? '$(this.hash).offset().top'

Comment: Already updated my question.

Comment: @DelightedD0D It's working when I click on the active page. But when I try to click from another page it'll not work.

Comment: don't post links to another site....that link won't represent the problem in the question as soon as you fix it and will render the question useless in the future

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to scroll to elements on another page that don't exist on the current page.

You need to read the hash on page load of new page and then scroll ... if that element exists

Within your current code...check if the target is in the page and then prevent the default, otherwise let the browser follow the url

Comment: So should I change my link id's like `/#handmade-jewellery` some sort of that?

Comment: No need...just check if the element exists in current page as well as have page load code that also checks for hash in url and scrolls on page load also. This is all assuming that you are loading full pages from server

Comment: @NikolayErmakov makes no sense to call window.location ... just let the browser default go there if the element doesn't exist in current page

Comment: simple ... `if($( this.hash).length){ /* prevent default and do scroll*/}` otherwise it's on another page..let the browser go there and check the hash on page load and do the scroll if hash target exists there also

Comment: @NikolayErmakov because that is a category heading for dropdown and has absolutely nothing to do with the problem related to scrolling to hash target

Comment: @NikolayErmakov that being said the href's are strange since they don't seem to point to another page and I suspect that is another problem also or oversimplified code in question

Comment: Some sort of this `$('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
 }, 1000, function() {
     location.hash = target;
 });` ???

Comment: @LeonardDrapeza Is your plan to let user select a submenu then open another page and then scroll to some place on that page?

Comment: Not open another page. Just redirect it to the page and scroll it down.

Comment: Like the effect here in stackoverflow when you try to check the comment in the inbox it'll redirect you to the latest comment

Comment: Then as @charlietfl wrote before you probably do not have elements with these id's on your page. Check that you have elements with ids: `handmade-jewellery`, `computer-graphic-jewellery-design`, `gem-sourcing`.